# My javascript function does delete, but not how I meant to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a small project where I have a function that does seem to work, but not how I meant to! Function that doesn't work:

```
function getRemoveBtn (target, i) {
  var removeBtn = $('<a/>', { 
    'class': 'btn btn-danger' 
  }).on('click', function() {
    $(target).remove(getWordPartInput(i));
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>');

  console.log(target);

  return removeBtn;
}
```

javascript/jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var id = 0;
var addOpdracht = $('<a/>', {
   'class': 'btn btn-success',
   'id': 'addOpdracht'
}).on('click', function(){
    $('form').append(getExerciseBlock(id));
    id++;
}).html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>');

$('form').append(addOpdracht);
})



function getAddBtn(target, i){
 var addBtn = $('<a/>', {
                'class': 'btn btn-primary'
            }).on('click', function(){
              $(target).append(getWordPartInput(i));
            }).html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>');
            console.log(target);
 return addBtn;
}


function getRemoveBtn(target, i){
 var removeBtn = $('<a/>', {
                'class': 'btn btn-danger'
            }).on('click', function(){
              console.log(target);
              $("#SyllablesGetWordPartInput").remove(target);
            }).html('<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>');
 return removeBtn;
 }



function getExerciseBlock(i){
  var eBlock = $('<div/>',{
 'id': i,
 'class': 'col-md-12, eBlock'
 });

    $(eBlock).append(getAudioBtn(i), getWordInput(i), getWordPartInput(i), 
 getRemoveBtn(i), getAddBtn(eBlock, i));

  return eBlock;
}


 function getAudioBtn(id, cValue){
   cValue = cValue || '';
   var audioBtn = $('<a/>', {
                'class': 'btn btn-primary'
            }).html('<i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>');
  return audioBtn;
}


 function getWordInput(id, cValue){
   cValue = cValue || '';
   var wInput = $('<input/>', {
                'class': 'form-group form-control',
                'type': 'text',
                'name': 'question_takeAudio_exerciseWord[]',
                'placeholder': 'Exercise',
                'id': 'exerciseGetWordInput'
            })
   return wInput;
}


 function getWordPartInput(id, cValue){
  cValue = cValue || '';
  var wpInput = $('<input/>', {
                  'class': 'form-group form-control',
                  'type': 'text',
                  'value': cValue,
                  'placeholder': 'Syllables',
                  'id': 'SyllablesGetWordPartInput'
              });
 return wpInput;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DanDy/hqy73b0h/

A fiddle for you guys to try it urself, please don't mind the layout. 
I somehow couldn't get that fixed, but the problem I have does occure (Yoopie I guess?)

What I am trying to accomplish: each red <kbd>-</kbd> button should take away the input fields I add and NOT the standard syllable input field that comes with the exercise input field (when clicked on the green button).

Each red button should work like the blue button too. They should only stick to their own div ID and NOT take away input fields from other div IDs.

However the problem I have: (and you most likely will encounter when you try my fiddle).

The first red button takes away my standard syllable input field AND it removes the input fields from other div IDs, yet the problem doesn't end there. All the other red buttons don't work at all.

Either my code has to be so garbage that it responds like this or it's something very little I'm missing out on. I'm sorry for any weird coding or code that should not be done the way I have, I'm new to javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question right.

You did not remove the correct element. You want to remove the parent of your button. I did this with `$(this).parent().remove();`.

I've updated your Fiddle so you can see the working code.

https://jsfiddle.net/hqy73b0h/1/

I hope this is what you where looking for.

UPDATE:

Like this? 
https://jsfiddle.net/hqy73b0h/2/

I did it with the `last-child` selector. If you make multiple elements of the same kind, you shouldn't use the same ID for each one. Use the same class instead.

Comment: almost, it should only delete the syllables you add with the blue "getAddBtn" and then from the parent element (the div ID).

Comment: Yes, but the second getRemoveBtn doesn't work and the first one still takes away the syllables I add in the second exercise colum. I would like to have the minus buttons work the exact same way as the blue add buttons, they add to their own div ID, as u can see the blue button doesn't add any extra syllables to the second exercise input field, the same should be for the red button but visa versa, its only allowed to target its own div ID and not another div ID. I hope this clarified a bit more